# Macro sum only filtered cells in table and copy to clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do some data entry and was wondering if I could copy the sum of FILTERED data onto clipboard with a macro?

I have a macro that copies sum of selected cells, but when in a table format and filtering it seems to sum everything in that range too. Please let me know.

There are 1665 Rows total in my data table starting at 22.

Thanks!

Comment: Right click on the table and click Table->Totals Row to show a row at the bottom of the table for totals. It will only sum the visible rows of that column.

Comment: Wow! I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 0):

No need to really use a macro, you can use the `SUMIFS` function https://support.office.com/en-in/article/SUMIFS-function-9dd6179e-cced-41dd-ac38-08fdf5b929e5  Basically you will use the criteria for filtering as the criteria for summing the values. I am not sure what your filtering criteria is, but let's you are filtering value that are great than 0 in column A rows 1 to 100.

```
SUMIFS(A1:A100, A1:A100, ">0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the table and click Table->Totals Row to show a row at the bottom of the table for totals. It will only sum the visible rows of that column.